# Selecting Data on JavaScript popup menu using Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using Selenium to test out a web site. The web site contains a date field, which when clicked, opens a popup from wherein I can choose the date.

My issue is that I wish to select a particular date using the Selenium IDE or Selenese. I have tried various methods, but have not been able to get a correct solution or been able to resolve it, except by manually specifying a date to the field in Selenese script. I am using Java to implement the test case.

An example could be checked by going to any airlines site and clicking on the date field for departure. The popup which comes up, I wish to capture a date on that. This could be a future date or the present date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement some code that will navigate calendar to the desired date. Depending on the calendar appearance it may be required to navigate to the next month or year, so you need the code that will determine what needs to be done and then emulate required events for Selenium.

We had the same task in our tests and we end up with either selecting today's date or by entering the date into the field directly. We also made a code that will allow to select any date on the calendar by we did this only because we needed to test the calendar widget and we were the authors of the widget so we knew how it was made. However it resulted in writing a lot of code

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE is limited in its ability to handle javascript. I've worked around it at times
by putting custom links in that do customized GETs, but it's a hack.

You could look at Sahi, which can do it. I haven't tried it though.

http://sahi.co.in/w/